# Output is `blank` space for the normal input on my C code

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  char str[100];
  scanf("%s", str[0]);
  printf("%c", str[1]);

  return 0;
}
```

I am running this code. I have entered "Jagrit" as an input. I expect the output of above program is 'j'. But instead i get nothing as a output just a blank space. Can anyone tell me why is it so and what was the error in the code ?

Comment: **C is different to C++**

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `scanf("%s","jagrit dolir");`?

Comment: scanf reads from standard input!

Comment: Just use strcpy(str, “blanks”); your intention is to copy the string to array instead of scanf().

Answer (score 1):

`scanf` expects the address of memrory to write to read data to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
     char str[100]; 
     scanf("%s", str); 
     printf("%c",str[0]); 
     return 0; 
}
```

Have a look at the example section of  [this doc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) on `scanf`.

What was your intention with `scanf("%s", "jargrit dolir")` ?

Answer (score 1):

This

```
scanf("%s","jagrit dolir");/*it doesn't put data into str, and doing that causes UB*/
```

So accessing `str[0]` may cause undefined behavior because `str` doesn't initialized & it's not having any data.

Instead use like below.

```
scanf("%s",str);/* now give input like  jagrit dolir */
```

And then print `str[0]`.

**Edit :-** since you modify the code.  Have you read the manual page of `scanf()` ?

`scanf("%s",str[0]);/* why you are not reading compiler warning here ?*/`

Here `%s` expects argument of `char*` but you provided `char` type.

Comment: I feel the OP is invoking UB even here: `scanf("%s","jagrit dolir");`

Comment: Yes @babon agree.

Answer (score 1):

if you just want to take a input as a string  can use fgets()
and just use str[0] to print the first character of the string 
note that
printf() is used to print values only;
here is the simple version of the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
# include<stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char str[100];
    fgets(str,100,stdin);
    printf("%c",str[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you use str[0] , you access it's value so the `scanf` should be like thit `scanf("%s",&str[0]);` or like this `scanf("%s",str);`
you also should expect the output to be 'a'

Answer (score -5):

try this code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char str[100];
    printf("%s","jagrit dolir");
    printf("%c",str[0]);        
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why would this work any better? What did you change and why?